# How can I initialize the data to the DRAM in gem5?

Tags: gem5

I'm new to gem5 and having a problem with initializing the data to the DRAM.

I want to preload the data in the hex file to the particular address on the DRAM.

Is there any way to do this?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

DRAM in gem5 inherit the class AbstractMemory(abstract_mem.cc), the correponding .py provide a parameter called 'image_file' to initialize the memory.
So you can write the following code in the config file, such as se.py:

```
system.mem_ctrls[0].dram.image_file = /path/to/your/file
```

Only the binary data format file are supported, transfer your original hex file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't convert your raw data to an image file, an alternative solution is to use the C++ interface in the source. Seeing as DRAM in gem5 is ultimately a SimObject, it has support for the `startup()` function.

For example, in the AbstractMemory class header, you can add the override declaration `void startup() override;`, and in the source you can add the support for loading in the appropriate hex values

```
void
AbstractMemory::startup()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

What may be useful is that the physical memory is tracked with by a pointer to what is essentially a long array that is indexed by physical address, so by calling `memcpy` to the address should fill that location with the address.